# How do I use typescript to print ngFor loop values in console?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4, ngfor

I'm using ngFor to print out a collection of values that are stored in firestore. The data is printed like I want it but I want a user to be able to "favorite" a certain item. Right now, i'm just trying to grab the correct data before I try to add it to their favorite collection in firestore. My issue is that everytime the favorite button is clicked, the value of the element doesn't change. It prints out the first "name" value of the collection everytime even though the html is different. Also, I'm using Ionic with AngularFire2.
Here's my page's html and the typescript function.

```
 <ion-card *ngFor="let item of workouts">
    <span>
      <ion-card>
        <img src="/assets/exercise1.jpg" alt="Picture not available"/>
        <ion-card>
          <h3 id="woDescript">{{item.Description}}</h3>
          <div class="btn">
            <ion-button (click)="faveButton()">
              <ion-icon name='star' slot="start"></ion-icon>
              Favorite
            </ion-button>
          </div>

        </ion-card>

        <ion-card-header>
          <ion-card-title id="workoutName">{{item.Name}}</ion-card-title>
        </ion-card-header>
      </ion-card>
    </span>
  </ion-card>
```

```
faveButton(){
      var record ={};
      var name = (document.getElementById('workoutName').innerHTML)
      var descript = (document.getElementById('woDescript').innerHTML);
      var image = "image";
      record['Name'] = name;
      record['Descript'] = descript;
      record['Image'] = image;
      console.log(record);
    }
```

When I print to the console, I just get the first value that is printed in the for loop for every card. It looks like this: 
{Name: "Pull-up", Descript: "A pull-up is an upper-body compound pulling exerci… pull-up performed with a palms-forward position.", Image: "image"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `id` to fetch values, which needs to be unique. If there are more than one elements with the same `id`, you get the first one.

But you can directly get the values in your function by passing `item`:

```
<ion-button (click)="faveButton(item)">
...
faveButton(item) { 
  // use item properties here
}
```